# Why do I get this error? Loading large text file to Blender

Tags: python

Hello Blender Community,

I am trying to simulate a machining process in blender. The cutting tool used is simplified via cylinder and its position is extracted to space delimited text file from NC Code.

Currently, the code I am running via text editor is

```
import bpy

with open(bpy.path.abspath("//cutting position trial.txt"),
       'r', buffering = 1) as content:

    for line in content:
        # extract tool position
        x, y, z = line.split(' ',2)

        # create tool
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
            vertices = 3000, 
            radius = 0.5, 
            depth = 10,
            location = (float(x), float(y), float (z))
            )

        # add BOOLEAN modifier
        bpy.data.objects['ISO 10791 M1 blank cd 0.0025'].modifiers.new('Boolean', 'BOOLEAN')
        bpy.data.objects['ISO 10791 M1 blank cd 0.0025'].modifiers['Boolean'].operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
        bpy.data.objects['ISO 10791 M1 blank cd 0.0025'].modifiers['Boolean'].object = bpy.data.objects["Cylinder"]
        bpy.data.objects['ISO 10791 M1 blank cd 0.0025'].modifiers['Boolean'].solver = 'CARVE'
        # activate the blank
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['ISO 10791 M1 blank cd 0.0025']
        # apply modifier
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Boolean")

        # Remove cylinder
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.data.objects['Cylinder'].select = True
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

The code works for small amount of lines, around 15 lines are tested.

However, when loading full file blender quit after a few seconds and give error file:

[image: Terminal Output]

Is there something wrong with the code? I thought the file was read line by line so the the problem should not happened.

The complete zip file can be downloaded from:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aUYUExuDTMFPYKpgOcB34_cXWutqMTPV/view?usp=sharing

Kind regards.
iwan

Comment: can you please supply a representative .txt file, so people can run the code straight from the TextEditor and help out.

Comment: added the downloadable zip.

Answer (score 1):

**Some of the way there**

Here is some changes to get you some of the way there.  Unfortunately I have a late version of 2.79 where the boolean modifier no longer has the `solver` property, so I can't be sure of result.

- add and remove the cylinder once at start and end respectively.
- set the cd object as active and select.
- reference the modifier when added, apply by reference (name).

Edited script:

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
    vertices = 3000, 
    radius = 0.5, 
    depth = 10,
    location = (0, 0, 0)
        )
cylinder = context.object
cylinder.select = False
cd = scene.objects['ISO 10791 M1 blank cd 0.0025']
scene.objects.active = cd
cd.select = True
with open(bpy.path.abspath("//cutting position trial.txt")) as content:            
    for i, line in enumerate(content):
        print(i)

        # extract tool position
        x, y, z = [float(n) for n in line.split(' ',2)]
        cylinder.location = (x, y, z + 5)
        scene.update() # may not be needed.
        # add BOOLEAN modifier
        m = cd.modifiers.new('Boolean', 'BOOLEAN')
        m.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
        m.object = cylinder
        #m.solver = 'CARVE'

        # apply modifier
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=m.name)
bpy.data.objects.remove(cylinder)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The BMesh solver gives wrong result for the operation. Using the Carve solver still result in the same error.